# How can I make the bot send a message once if I reached 55 minutes?

Tags: javascript, datetime, discord.js

```js
var d = new Date();
if(d.getMinutes() === 55)
```

How can I make the bot send a message once if I reached 55 minutes?

Comment: If you want to handle that with JavaScript, it's pretty simple with `setTimeout ()`

Comment: @Fritzdultimate Can you explain?

Comment: Someone already answered it, you just need to pass the number of milliseconds you want, for 55mins, that should be 1000 * 60 * 55

Answer (score 1):

Use [setTimeout() function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Example:

```js
setTimeout(() => { // function

console.log('This will be logged after five seconds')

}, 5000) // amount of time to wait in ms. for this example I used five seconds (5000 ms)
```

Example with schedule function:

```js
function schedule(time, triggerThis) {
    // get hour and minute from hour:minute param received, ex.: '16:00'
    const hour = Number(time.split(':')[0]);
    const minute = Number(time.split(':')[1]);

    // create a Date object at the desired timepoint
    const startTime = new Date();
    startTime.setHours(hour, minute);
    const now = new Date();

    // increase timepoint by 24 hours if in the past
    if (startTime.getTime() < now.getTime()) {
      startTime.setHours(startTime.getHours() + 24);
    }

    // get the interval in ms from now to the timepoint when to trigger the alarm
    const firstTriggerAfterMs = startTime.getTime() - now.getTime();

    // trigger the function triggerThis() at the timepoint
    // create setInterval when the timepoint is reached to trigger it every day at this timepoint
    setTimeout(function () {
      triggerThis();
      setInterval(triggerThis, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    }, firstTriggerAfterMs);
  }
  
  schedule('14:00', () => {
  //        ^^^^^ time to trigger function
  
  // send message
  client.channels.cache.get(id) // id of channel you want to send message in
  .send('this is a message')
  })
```

Comment: And how does that send a message every 55 mins? I'm trying to find something that won't stop working after restarting the bot.

Comment: I edited my original answer with a function that will work even after restarting your bot. Hopefully, it helps 

Comment: Setting the time should zero the seconds and milliseconds: `startTime.setHours(hour, minute, 0, 0)` or preferably use defaults and allow them to be passed: `let [h, m, s, ms] = time.split(/\D/); startTime.setHours(h||0, m||0, s||0, ms||0)`. Also setting the lag until running would be more efficient as `startTime - Date.now()`. Lastly, not all days are 24 hours long where daylight saving is observed and *setInterval* drifts, so the *setInterval* approach is not robust.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using cron to schedule a message every 55th minute. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron